# Appending Values from Column in txt file to Variable List

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data file with two columns of numbers. I am trying to assign these two columns to two separate variables. For example:

```
Col_1      Col_2
30         50
25         75
```

I want to define variables a and b to be:

```
a = [30, 25]
b = [50, 75]
```

My code currently is:

```
#f is defined as the data txt file
a = []
b = []

with open(f) as file_in:
    lines = file_in.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        a.append(row[0])
        b.append(row[1])
print(lines)
```

but I'm getting an error. HOw do I do the final step where I append the values?

Comment: How about showing us the error? And where do you define `row`? Perhaps you mean `line[0]` and `line[1]`?  Though that will only pick two Characters... Perhaps use a csv reader? Assuming your file 'columns' are comma delimited? Or perhaps tab delimited?  Or fixed width? (There's so much ambiguity here thst it's impossible to answer.). Or, just use pandas?

Comment: Hi - a quick suggestion: as the other user pointed too, please paste an extract of the error you're receiving to help others diagnose it quickly. Thanks!